# How do I use user input to select data from a 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I need to preface this by saying that I am incredibly new to coding. I'm taking a course at a college for my apprenticeship at work. It's one day a week and I've been going for about 7 weeks now. We're doing Java and we've more or less learnt the fundamentals and now we've been given an assignment to create a simple hotel booking system. We don't need to display nor are we graded on our OOP techniques. This all just needs to be done within one class.

With that out the way, onto the matter at hand.

A part of the assignment requires us to allow the user to select a room type (Penthouse, king room, etc.) then select how many days they want to stay (either 7 or 14 days). My tutor said that the easiest way to do it would be to have a variable for each required bit of information, but said it would look incredibly messy. He then said the hardest way to do it would be using a 2D array, so I wanted to give that a crack. This is what the Array looks like:

```
int[][] roomSel = new int[6][2];
        roomSel[0][0] = 700;
        roomSel[0][1] = 1400;
        roomSel[1][0] = 630;
        roomSel[1][1] = 1260;
        roomSel[2][0] = 560;
        roomSel[2][1] = 1120;
        roomSel[3][0] = 490;
        roomSel[3][1] = 980;
        roomSel[4][0] = 1120;
        roomSel[4][1] = 2240;
        roomSel[5][0] = 350;
        roomSel[5][1] = 700;
```

The first number references the room type (there are 6 types), and the second number references the number of days they want to stay (0 = 7 days and 1 = 14 days). The data they hold is the price for their selection.

So my question is, how would I go about using user input to select the appropriate data from this array? I've done a fair bit of googling and everything I found talks about using user input to populate the array. Which isn't what I need as the array is already populated.

If I'm not making any sense then please let me know and I'll try to clarify my problem further.

Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[][] roomSel = new Integer[6][2];
    roomSel[0][0] = 700;
    roomSel[0][1] = 1400;
    roomSel[1][0] = 630;
    roomSel[1][1] = 1260;
    roomSel[2][0] = 560;
    roomSel[2][1] = 1120;
    roomSel[3][0] = 490;
    roomSel[3][1] = 980;
    roomSel[4][0] = 1120;
    roomSel[4][1] = 2240;
    roomSel[5][0] = 350;
    roomSel[5][1] = 700;


    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please select room type: ");
    int roomType = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter 0 for 7 days and 1 for 14 days: ");
    int days = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Price is " + roomSel[roomType][days]);
}
```

This example is very minimalistic and needs improvement ;) Have fun.

Comment: `new Integer[11][11]` initializes an array of 11x11, it should be `new Integer[6][2]`

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood this correctly, your aim is to find the price for a given type of room and the number of days the room is occupied. You don't need an array for this purpose at all.

Use hashmap for the type of room. The key corresponds to the type of room and value corresponds to its price per day. Example: Hashmap=`{0:100, 1:200, 2:100, 3:200, 4:100, 5:200}`.

Based on user input, which is your key to this hashmap, get its value, which is the price per day. multiply this value with the user input of 'number of days'

Answer (score 0):

Reading user input can be done by reading from `System.in`. You might want to give `java.util.Scanner` a try. Print some text, ask the user to enter a choice and read the value with `java.util.Scanner#nextInt()`. Make sure the value is in the allowed range.

Ask for two values, the first for the room category, the second for the duration.

To be honest, your array does not make much sense to me. It seems to contain pre-calculated values for possible choices and combinations. Not sure, why you would want to do this.

When you have category and a duration, you can calculate the price easily. All you have to do is find the correct price for the category per day. You *could* use an array for that, eg. `price[0]=100`. But what's your program going to do with it?

Is it going to just print the final price? Do you want to keep track of the records, ...?

Comment: Yeah they're precalculated because the only options they can choose are 7 days or 14 days. In the assignment sheet each room has a "price per day" but seeing as they can only choose 7 days or 14 days I thought it would make more sense to calculate the total beforehand.

So once they make their selection I can take the price and then I need to do other stuff with it like add VAT etc.

Comment: No good idea. Your computer is amazing in doing calculations. And he is so f***ing fast. You should try to avoid doing this yourself in the source code. Otherwise your code is going to become a real mess and will be hard to maintain and hard to extend.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you are new to coding, I assume you have heard of Enums. This is a nice way to keep your code clean as Enums are lists of constants like unchangeable variables and in your case they can hold some information regarding the room type and days to stay, instead of just using integers for the array index that mean nothing to room type or days to stay.

Instead of having a comment or something that reminds you that roomType 1 is Double room, you can use Enums like below:

For room type:

```
enum RoomType{
    SINGLE(0, "Single Room"),
    DOUBLE(1, "Double Room"),
    TRIPLE(2, "Triple Room"),
    QUEEN(3, "Queen"),
    KING(4, "King"),
    SUITE(5, "Suite");

    private final int value;
    private final String type;

    RoomType(final int val, final String type) {
        this.value = val;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public static RoomType getByValue(int val) {
        for(RoomType e : values()) {
            if(e.value == val) return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value + "\t\t: " + type ;
    }
}
```

For the number of days to stay:

```
enum Stay{
    SHORT(0, "7 Days"),
    LONG(1, "14 Days");

    private final int value;
    private final String type;

    Stay(final int value, final String type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public static Stay getByValue(int val) {
        for(Stay e : values()) {
            if(e.value == val) return e;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value + "\t\t: " + type ;
    }
}
```

What the above Enums does? They define constant values for RoomType and Stay. They can return either an integer (like the index of your array) or a String that can be used to print a menu.

You can use the Enums as in the following main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[][] roomSel = new int[RoomType.values().length][Stay.values().length];
        roomSel[RoomType.SINGLE.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 350;
        roomSel[RoomType.SINGLE.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 700;
        roomSel[RoomType.DOUBLE.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 490;
        roomSel[RoomType.DOUBLE.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 980;
        roomSel[RoomType.TRIPLE.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 560;
        roomSel[RoomType.TRIPLE.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 1120;
        roomSel[RoomType.QUEEN.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 630;
        roomSel[RoomType.QUEEN.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 1260;
        roomSel[RoomType.KING.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 700;
        roomSel[RoomType.KING.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 1400;
        roomSel[RoomType.SUITE.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()] = 1120;
        roomSel[RoomType.SUITE.getValue()][Stay.LONG.getValue()] = 2240;

        RoomType roomTypeUserSelection = null;
        Stay stayUserSelection = null;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (roomTypeUserSelection == null) {
            System.out.println("-- ROOM TYPES --");
            for (RoomType rt : RoomType.values()) {
                System.out.println(rt);
            }
            System.out.println("Please select room type: ");
            String roomTypeStr = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                roomTypeUserSelection = RoomType.getByValue(Integer.parseInt(roomTypeStr));
            }catch(Exception e){ }
            if (roomTypeUserSelection==null){
                System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Try again");
            }
        }

        while (stayUserSelection == null) {
            System.out.println("-- Stay Days --");
            for (Stay stay : Stay.values()) {
                System.out.println(stay);
            }
            System.out.println("Please select how many days to stay: ");
            String stayStr = scanner.nextLine();
            try {
                stayUserSelection = Stay.getByValue(Integer.parseInt(stayStr));
            }catch(Exception e){ }
            if (stayUserSelection==null){
                System.out.println("Invalid User Input. Try again");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Room Type : " + roomTypeUserSelection.toString());
        System.out.println("Stay for  : " + stayUserSelection.toString());
        System.out.println("Total Cost : " + roomSel[roomTypeUserSelection.getValue()][stayUserSelection.getValue()]);
    }
}
```

See how the index is selected for each place of the array: `roomSel[RoomType.SINGLE.getValue()][Stay.SHORT.getValue()]` which is translated as `roomSel[0][0]`.

Then you may do a while loop until the user selects a valid type. An Enum iteration on its values `RoomType.values()` invokes the toString() method for each of the value on the Enum and prints a menu. Then the user input (taken as a String * ) is parsed into Integer and if it fails: a. user enters a non integer value or b.User enters a value outside of the Enum values, the `roomTypeUserSelection` remains null and the loop continues.

At the end, the `roomTypeUserSelection` and `stayUserSelection` contains the user selection Enum, where you can either get the index, or the type as a String (e.g. 3 or Queen).

A sample output of the above program is:

```
-- ROOM TYPES --
0       : Single Room
1       : Double Room
2       : Triple Room
3       : Queen
4       : King
5       : Suite
Please select room type: 
4
-- Stay Days --
0       : 7 Days
1       : 14 Days
Please select how many days to stay: 
2
Invalid User Input. Try again
-- Stay Days --
0       : 7 Days
1       : 14 Days
Please select how many days to stay: 
1
Room Type  : 4      : King
Stay for   : 1      : 14 Days
Total Cost : 1400
```